# ASP.net MVC DisplayNameFor nested model in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, controller

I have a view in my ASP.net MVC project which is associated to a controller (SubmissionController) and class (Submission).

In the view, I am displaying some values from the class using:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.Created)
```

This works perfectly, but what I want to achieve now, is to be able to get the display name of a Collection nested within the model I reference above.

To make that clearer; I am viewing a single Submission of many Submissions in the view (using the Details function of the SubmissionController). Each submission has many Photos, and it is these photos I want to display in the Submission details view along with the submission details themselves.

To display the photos, I have the following piece of code creating a table of photos...

```
            <tbody>
            @For Each item In Model.Photos
                Dim currentItem = item
                @<tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Photo_ID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Photo_Status1.Value)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Photo_Size)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Photo_Taken)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            Next
        </tbody>
```

Whilst untested, I believe the above code should work just fine.

With this in mind, How on earth do I get the DisplayNameFor values for Photo fields/properties?

This apparently, does not work!

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Photos.Photo_Size)
```

**By the way, I don't want to write in the header names manually, they must come from the model.**

### Answer

[DigitalD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1649762/digitald)'s answer was almost there, here is the solution.

```
@Dim photoModel = New Photo()
@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(photoModelx) photoModel.Photo_ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Photos.Photo_Size)` won't work because `model.Photos` is likely an `IEnumerable` and doesn't have a Photo_Size property. You might get away with passing in an empty model item like so:

```
@Dim displayModel = new Photo()
@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(displayModel) displayModel.Photo_Size)
```

etc.

Comment: As it happens this was almost exactly what I needed to do! I had to change the variable name in the Function to something arbitrary or it would just use the Views model by default.

Comment: As for MVC5, you might get an error in this case which would say that your DisplayNameFor call is ambiguous. So you need to specify the type arguments explicitly. In C# it'd be like `@(Html.DisplayNameFor<Photo, int>(model => displayModel.Photo_Size))`

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you are trying to get the name of the field you are showing ("Photo Taken", "Photo Size", etc)?  If this is the case, I would suggest using DataAnnotations and LabelFor(item=>item.Field).  This will give you what you are looking for I believe.